# Ejecutar una operacion luego de eliminar un documento de forma atomica en mongo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo los siguientes esquemas:

```
const ClienteSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El cliente es requerido"]
    }

    apellido: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El cliente es requerido"]
    }

})

const AlquilerSchema = new Schema({
    
    fecha_pago: {
        type: Date,
        required: [true, "La fecha de pago es requerida"]
    }

    cliente: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Cliente',
        required: [true, "El cliente es requerido"]
    }
})
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que al eliminar un cliente se eliminen todos los alquileres que realizo el cliente de forma atómica.

Encontré que Mongo Atlas provee un sistema de triggers, yo no lo puedo usar ya que mi BD no esta alojada en Mongo Atlas.

Lo que hice fue utilizar los middleware que provee mongoose, pero no estoy seguro de si esta operacion es atomica, es decir, si al eliminar el cliente y ocurre un fallo al eliminar los alquileres, el cliente no es eliminado.

```
ClienteSchema.post('remove', doc => {

    AlquilerSchema.deleteMany({cliente: doc._id})

});
```

Comment: ¿Es tu servidor un conjunto de réplica o un servidor independiente? Porque dependiendo de esto, podrás usar transacciones o no. ¿Puedes aclarar este punto? Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras, es un servidor independiente de momentos. Suponiendo que la DB la subo a Mongo Atlas, ellos me proveen de un nodo "master" y 2 nodos de replica, ¿En este caso usaría transacciones?¿la transacción se debe indicar de alguna forma que es hacia el nodo replica o lo gestiona el nodo master?

Comment: Las transacciones las maneja el Servidor automáticamente, la respuesta que te han dado sólo te serviría en una configuración de réplica o en un clúster fragmentado (sharded cluster). Para un servidor independiente existen formas de *imitar* una transacción. Por otro lado, toda operación sobre un documento en MongoDB es atómica, sin importar el tamaño o lo complejo del documento. Eso para que lo tengas en cuenta. Espero poder dar una respuesta pronto sobre este asunto, que es muy interesante y tu pregunta es muy buena. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por responder, leyendo la documentación de Mongo sugiere utilizar otro tipo de modelado para solucionar este problema, una de las posibles soluciones es el Patron Bucket, el problema es que el documento no debe crecer mas de 16MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución para lo que buscas es realizar una transacción con Mongoose, de esta forma te aseguras de que todos los documentos se eliminan correctamente y si ocurriera un error volvería al estado anterior de la transacción.

Sobre los `middlewares` de Mongoose (pre y post), ten en cuenta de que están pensados para manejar posibles errores que pueda ocurrir en las acciones que quieras realizar (save, update, etc.).

Te detallo un ejemplo de una transacción para que puedas entenderla:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

/**
 * Method Transaction
 * 
 * @param {string | ObjectId} cliente          ObjectId del cliente
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
module.exports = async function (cliente) {
    // Generamos una Session para agrupar todas las acciones en la transacción
    const session = await mongoose.startSession()
    session.startTransaction()

    try {
        await mongoose.model('Cliente') // Nombre del modelo que le has indicado al generar el Schema (ej. db.model('Cliente', ClienteSchema)) 
                   .deleteOne({ _id: cliente }, { session }) // Añadimos la session
       
        await mongoose.model('Alquiler').deleteMany({ cliente },  { session })

        await session.commitTransaction() // Ejecutamos la transacción

        return true
    } catch (e) {
        // Si ocurre un error, aborta la transacción y deshacer cualquier cambio que pudiera haber ocurrido
        await session.abortTransaction()

        return false
    } finally {
        // Finaliza la session
        session.endSession()
    }
}
```

Esta función se podría añadir como un método al esquema de la colección `Cliente` y así llamarlo cuando este instanciado, te pongo un ejemplo de como podría ir el método en el Schema (me salto el paso de las conexión) y como se usaría:

```
// Archivo Cliente.js

const ClienteSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El cliente es requerido"]
    }

    apellido: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El cliente es requerido"]
    }

})

ClienteSchema.methods.transactionRemove = async function () {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession()
    session.startTransaction()

    try {
        await mongoose.model('Cliente').deleteOne({ _id: this._id }, { session }) 
       
        await mongoose.model('Alquiler').deleteMany({ cliente: this._id },  { session })

        await session.commitTransaction() 

        return true
    } catch (e) {
        await session.abortTransaction()

        return false
    } finally {
        // Finaliza la session
        session.endSession()
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cliente', ClienteSchema)
```

Se usaria:

```
const Cliente = require('./Cliente.js')

const removeClient = async (nombre) => {

      const cliente = Cliente.findOne({ nombre: nombre })

      const results = await cliente.transactionRemove()

      return results
}

removeClient('pepe')
```

Espero que con esta explicación puedas resolver tu problema.

Para cualquier consulta, no dudes en preguntar.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por responder @planta4 , fue muy clara tu respuesta. Te hago una consulta, es conveniente llamar al metodo .exec() luego del deleteOne() y deleteMany() en el metodo transactionRemove()?

Comment: El OP (@Doormut) no indica que su Servidor sea un conjunto de réplica ([Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)). ¿Cómo puede esta solución basada en [transacciones](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) ser una solución al problema del OP? Cuando en la documentación se establece que: *MongoDB soporta transacciones solamente en servidores de réplica y no en servidores independientes*. Creo que el OP debería aclarar esto entonces. Saludos